# Blog Post URL In flutter Web

Tags: flutter, firebase, url

I'm currently building a blog website using Flutter web with Firebase. I'm looking to implement a feature where each blog post has its own unique URL that users can share and be redirected to. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve this? You can check out my project on GitHub [here](https://github.com/rafay99-epic/Portfolio). Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

A solution to my Problem or a Direction in which I can search upon

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation/url-strategies?